# Howto sync offline sheet from Sheets app

Tags: google-sheets, synchronization, mobile, google-sheets-offline

I did some offline work on a google sheet file on my mobile using Sheets app. I actually did not realize that I am offline, as I never set this option, at least not on purpose.

After I connected to the file using laptop browser, and did some extra work. Only than I realized I do not see the changes I made on the mobile app. Reopen the app, and the changes were lost as the file was synced with the last edit on the laptop, which did not have these edits.

So two questions:

1. Is there some sign to indicates "file is offline"?
2. How to force sync from mobile app, after working offline?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about using a mobile app. It might be on-topic in [android.se] or [apple.se].

Answer (score 1):

1. When you do online work in a mobile application, loss of connection will be displayed as a message of `No connection. You can still edit recent files or create new ones`. This means that you can continue with the automatically created offline version of your file, or manually create another copy of the your file, which, when you resume the Internet connection, will be synchronized with the cloud.
2. After working offline, when an Internet connection appears, your offline version of the file itself automatically synchronizes with the version located in the cloud. The only thing is that in the final file all changes made at the time of synchronization will be recorded.

For example:

In the morning your offline file in a mobile application without an internet connection looked like this:

```
A1 | Text1 | 1.2
A2 | Text2 | 3.4
A3 |
```

At lunch, working on a desktop with an Internet connection, your file looked like this:

```
A1 | 
A2 | Text3 | 5.6
A3 |
A4 | Text4
```

In the evening after dinner, you reopened the file on your mobile application, but found that there is no Internet connection. After you reconnected, there was a file sync in the cloud.

In the end, both in the cloud and on the mobile device, your file will look:

```
A1 | Text1 | 1.2
A2 | Text3 | 5.6
A3 | 
A4 | Text4
```

i.e. online file version synchronized with the latest changes.

However, I browser version, You can try to click on `Last edit was N minutes ago` message and after that it will open `Version history` page, where you can see all the changes that have occurred to the file in time.